# calculus inequality proof using mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Use the mean value theorem to prove that if $\displaystyle ~|x|<\frac{\pi}2 ~,~~ |y|<\frac{\pi}2~,$ then
>   $$|\sin(y) - \sin(x)| \leq |y-x| \leq |\tan(y) - \tan(x)|$$

What I did was using the mean value theorem using $\sin(x)$ as the function to get
$$\frac{ \sin(x) - \sin(y) }{ x-y } = \sin'(c) = \cos(c)$$
for some $c$ inbetween $x$ and $y$, and since the value of $\cos(x)$ for every $x$ goes around $1$ and $-1$ 
$$\left| \frac{ \sin(x) - \sin(y) }{ x-y }\right| \leq 1$$
but I'm stuck here

Comment: So, you have proved the first inequality. Can you use the same idea to prove the right inequality, using MVT for $\tan$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $f(x)=\tan{x}$, then by mean value theorem $$\frac{\tan{x}-\tan{y}}{x-y}=\tan'(c)=\sec^2({c})\geq1$$

Comment: ok so with this I get (using the transitive property of inequalities) 
 |sin(y)−sin(x)|≤|y−x|≤|tan(y)−tan(x)| but where does the hypothesis come in play?  how do the x|<π/2,|y|<π/2 relate to his?

Comment: in the case of $\tan{x}$ it is necessary to guarantee continuity, for apply the theore

Comment: ohhhhhhhh, ok, thank you dude